# What is this choppy defect called and what was it caused by?

Tags: hand-tools

What causes the splitty defect pictured below? Is there a special name for it? I think that working it out with hand planes would require removing too much of the surrounding wood. (Am I mistaken in that suspicion?) What hand-tools or materials would smooth out the defect with minimal wood-loss?

[image: d]

Comment: Please avoid "Best way to do XXX" as this invites subjective, not objective, responses.

Comment: It's hard to tell what's going on here. An initial glance suggested some of this is tearout but the locations are wrong, so then I was thinking it looks a little like the original rough surface from sawing remained after the board was further processed (although it would be unusually coarse and ragged for that). The more I look at it the more it looks like it could simply be crushing or scraping damage. Are there other boards like this or is it an isolated example?

Comment: looks to me like damage from banding or possibly from forklift tines

Comment: +1 to the crushing/scraping/ general mishandling diagnosis. The OP needs to either find a better wood merchant or (if possible) choose better from the pile. To smooth, use wood filler.

Comment: @bowlturner, I didn't think of banding, but that could be some of this for sure. Forklift damage was my eventual conclusion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have no idea if there's a name for it. ("chatter marks" maybe?) I've always assumed that to be damage from processing or handling during the lumber sawing processes. As the wood is cut, it is frequently moved from one place to the other during the process by falling on to moving chains or belts. I imagine the guys at the saw mill have a name for it, but I doubt that it goes much further than those circles.

(Gratuitous video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YrJas4_L4Wo It's a long one, but shows the whole process.) Maybe this is more to the point: https://youtu.be/YrJas4_L4Wo?t=180

As others have suggested it could be damage from the banding and or shipping processes as well. It looks like the photo shows a construction grade SPF 2x4 and the damage is consistent with what I've seen very frequently in those products.

This particular "defect" would be considered insignificant in that context and largely ignored during framing/construction. Nobody building a house would take the time to "fix" the boards or reject them for this.

Damage like this is another reason why building "nice" furniture or wooden objects that are meant to show a "higher degree of craftsmanship" with construction grade lumber isn't usually done. The trends for "farmhouse" furniture and so on has gone against this general practice recently.

Probably the best way to get rid of this would be to run the board through a thickness planer or use a hand plane if that's more to your liking. I suppose it could be done by sanding as well... but that's a lot of sanding. If the finished object is something that you intend to paint, wood filler could be used I'd imagine.

Perhaps the best ways to deal with this, if you didn't want to remove the damage, would be to turn the board over (if possible) so that this surface is hidden, be more selective about which boards you take home with you to avoid the problem entirely, or make it a "design feature" of what it is you are building.